Random dots for 3D printer turntable
I use Blender to make 3D models that I can then print with a 3D printer. I also have a 3D scanner and a turntable. I have a turntable (picture 1) to scan objects, but it needs markers to be able to keep track of the object. (unfortunately my turntable has no markers). My turntable has a black top without markers. So now I have to stick small round white stickers on the turntable top to be able to do this. So it is easier to make/3D print a turntable top where these white circles are already printed on/in which I can then place over the turntable top.
My question is how can I place white circles randomly on the turntable top, like in picture 2.



May I recommend to read this post: How do I add random spotting to the same face in cycles? ?

My advice would be: buy some stickers designed for this and use them, or buy some double sided sticky tape, print some stickers on paper put the sticky tape on the other side, cut them out and then use them. Even if you want to print one sheet, placing 20 dots by had takes 2 minutes, so no need for any automation or procedural modelling and no need for this delay. Why overcomplicate things?..

You can set up an orthographic camera to match scene dimensions to the dimensions on rendered images assuming some DPI resolution so you can render some images ready to print on a regular paper printer, but why would you go through all of this when most software dedicated to this already has this functionality?.. You can use Inkscape for example. Is there a good reason for you to try to do this in Blender?

Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see What should I do if no one answers my question?

You do not have to delete a question, you can edit it instead of posting a new one.
